# Fire JS function when people picker completes

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

Is there a way to trigger a JS function when a People picker completes and finds a user? I'm developing a SharePoint 2013 app using client side development pattern.

Thanks for your suggestion Per, I have tried adding the OnUserResolvedClientScript into the control as follows but its not working, not sure if I can add it in this way?

```
// First we need to get the selected user from the person selected in the people picker
$(document).ready(function () {

// Specify the unique ID of the DOM element where the
// picker will render.
initializePeoplePicker('employeePickerSpan');});

// Render and initialize the client-side People Picker.
function initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId) {
// Create a schema to store picker properties, and set the properties.
var schema = {};
schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = true;
schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
schema['OnUserResolvedClientScript'] = 'MyPickerUserResolved';
schema['Width'] = '250px';

// Render and initialize the picker. 
// Pass the ID of the DOM element that contains the picker, an array of initial
// PickerEntity objects to set the picker value, and a schema that defines
// picker properties.
this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);

}

function MyPickerUserResolved(topElementId,  MyPickerUserResolvedusers) {
// users is set to GetAllUserInfo()
// Get the people picker object from the page.
var employeePicker =    this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.employeePickerSpan_TopSpan;

// Get information about all employees.
var employees = employeePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
var employeeInfo = '';
for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
    var employee = employees[i];
    for (var employeeProperty in employee) {
        employeeInfo += employeeProperty + ':  ' + employee[employeeProperty] + '<br>';
    }
}
$('#employeelineManager').html(employeeInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On creation of the ClientPeoplePicker you can set the `OnUserResolvedClientScript` property to a function like:

```
function MyPickerUserResolved (topElementId, users) { 
    // users is set to GetAllUserInfo()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Per, managed to work out the following based on your post...<span id="employeePickerSpan" onmouseout="MyPickerUserResolved()" /> seems to work the way i need it!

Comment: actually i opted out of the mouseout, slowed the page down way too much, Per's solution worked great.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some jQuery to identify when the field on the page changes.  The DIV for the people picker will have plain text for items not yet checked (i.e. if you typed a name, but didn't hit check names) and a span for each item that it has checked.

Here are some examples of how to monitor a DIV like that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979738/fire-jquery-event-on-div-change

Answer (score 0):

This function work on Internet Explorer for me:

```
function MyPickerUserResolved (topElementId, users) {                    
  //prevent users == null
  if(users.length != 0){
    var UserManager = users[0].Description;
    alert(UserManager); // show message contains on user position 1;
  }
}
```